# Flutter how to share image on assets folder?

Tags: image, flutter, share, file-not-found

With this code I keep getting the error "ENOENT (No such file or directory), null, null, null)". How can I share a file on the assets folder?

```
Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    Share.shareFiles(['${directory.path}/baws.png'], text: 'Great picture');
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First get your image as bytes and copy to temp file.

```
      final bytes = await rootBundle.load('assets/image.jpg');
      final list = bytes.buffer.asUint8List();

      final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      final file = await File('${tempDir.path}/image.jpg').create();
      file.writeAsBytesSync(list);
```

Then use share package to share it, should work;

```
Share.shareFiles(['${file.path}'], text: 'Great picture');
```

Comment: This worked! Omg thank you! I have been at this for many days :(.
Now it says direct share not available. If you happen to know where I can search to find the issue it would be much appreciated. If not, thank you so much anyway!

Comment: No problem happy to solve it. Could you please share the full error message?

Comment: It is fixed! Thank you, have a great day :)

Comment: @Muhtar `getTemporaryDirectory()` showing me error. Is there any special thing to `import` that I am missing?

Comment: Okay, now I found the package Path Provider (https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) that solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're facing comes from the method `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();` it doesn't give you the right path.

It gives you the path of the hidden directory where the app store data.

You may want to update your code with something like so:

```dart
// old code
Share.shareFiles(['${directory.path}/baws.png'], text: 'Great picture');


// new one
Share.shareFiles(['assets/images/baws.png'], text: 'Great picture');
```

Don't forget to put your 'baws.png' in the folder named `assets` with a subfolder named `image` to match the example, and to declare it in your `pubspec.yaml`

The folder `assets` need to be at the root of your project directory.

You can find more information on the [official documentation here.](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images)

Comment: The asset works when adding an ImageAsset widget, but doesn't work with the code you sent me. I did all that and it still gives me assets/images/baws.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0):

```
                      // import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
                      // import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
                      // import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';
                      // import 'dart:io'; 
                      // share_plus: any
                      // path_provider: any
shareFile(){
                      ByteData imagebyte = await rootBundle
                          .load('assets/images/kissing_image_real.png');
                      final temp = await getTemporaryDirectory();
                      final path = '${temp.path}/image1.jpg';
                      File(path).writeAsBytesSync(imagebyte.buffer.asUint8List());
                      await Share.shareFiles([path], text: 'Image Shared');
```

}