# How to share image from assets/ images in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

i tried different packages like share plus to share packages from assets but always getting different error here is my code

```
 ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
                _shareImage(randomAdditionalData);
              }, child: Text('Send to daddy')),
            )
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _shareImage(String imagePath) async {
    await Share.shareFiles([imagePath], text: 'Shared image');
  }
```

thank you in advance

Comment: what errors? Kindly include in your post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter how to share image on assets folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68135764/flutter-how-to-share-image-on-assets-folder)